# Addition of missing data after floor_date / detect and fill in missing data gaps

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate, floor

I would like to sum up a larger set of data per month. `floor_date` offers the right functionality to sum up the data from the individual days on a monthly level. But unfortunately I need to make sure that all months are included in the final table. The initial data therefore does not always cover all months, but after floor_date there must be 0 in the corresponding months; the rows / months must not simply be missing. How can I ensure this automatically?

The following exemplary code clarifies my problem:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time =  c(as.Date("01-01-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y"), as.Date("02-01-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y"), as.Date("01-03-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y")),
  text = c("A", "A", "B")
  )


df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(month = floor_date(time, unit = "month")) %>%
  select(text, month) %>%
  group_by(month, text) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

df2

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   month [2]
  month      text      n
  <date>     <fct> <int>
1 2020-01-01 A         2
2 2020-03-01 B         1
```

It should be recognized that there is no data for B in month 2020-01, no data for A&B in month 2020-02 and no data for A in month 2020-03: this rows should be added with value 0.

Unfortunately, so far I have not found a solution to solve the problem in an automated way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal Sorry that my problem is dragging on for so long. In the code, only the naming of the text was different (A > AB etc). But I already considered this in your code and still did not get the result you showed. In my case there is the additional column .groups with "drop" as content and no additional rows showing a 0.

Thank you so much for helping me again!

Comment: The above code is now absolutely correct and coherent. Nevertheless the question remains, why I can't execute exactly your code (as it stands there, not adapted to anything) in the same way / get a different result

Comment: by the way @Alex, have you checked your tidyr/tidyverse version that it is updated??

Comment: Okay okay, I had to update my whole R version, then updated all packages again: Your solution works perfectly. My bad. Thank you very much for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand the need of using `format` while mutating the variable for a given month (floor_date).  This formatting turns the variable into character type and hence no further calculations can be performed.

Remove that step, and use `tidyr::complete` you can fill missing months as shown under-

```r
df <- data.frame(
  time =  c(as.Date("01-01-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y"), as.Date("02-01-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y"), as.Date("01-03-2020", format = "%d-%m-%Y")),
  text = c("A", "A", "B")
)

library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = F)
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>%
  mutate(month = floor_date(time, unit = "month")) %>%
  group_by(text, month) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  complete(nesting(text), month = seq.Date(from = min(month), to = max(month), by = '1 month'), fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  text  month          n
  <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1 A     2020-01-01     2
2 A     2020-02-01     0
3 A     2020-03-01     0
4 B     2020-01-01     0
5 B     2020-02-01     0
6 B     2020-03-01     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal: Already did this. above you find a updated version including the extended group_by. Thank You for all your efforts!

Comment: See edited answer @Alex_, and please tell if that serves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Base R option using `cut` -

```
stack(table(cut(df$time,'month')))[2:1]

#         ind values
#1 2020-01-01      2
#2 2020-02-01      0
#3 2020-03-01      1
```